# Не работает telebot parse mode HTML

Tags: python, telebot

У меня есть скрипт который создает строку, пусть это будет:

```
s = ''
for i in range(5):
  s+=('<b>'+str(i)+'</b>\n')
```

По окончанию это должно отправляться через бота в parse mode html

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,s,parse_mode= 'HTML')
```

Но бот отправляет без форматирования.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, что возвращает send_message?

Comment: `<b>0<b>
<b>1</b>
<b>2</b>
<b>3</b>
<b>4</b>`

Comment: Оффтоп, скобки лишние, можно сделать проще: `s += f'<b>{i}</b>\n'`

Comment: знаю, но смысл не в этом)